# How to get AWS Cognito access token with username and password in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a C# client application using .NET Core 3.1 which needs to use AWS Cognito user pools for user authentication.

As this is a client application I can't use `AdminInitiateAuth` etc and only have access to: user pool ID, client ID and the user-provided username and password.

I'm porting code from an existing JavaScript client application that uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js but I'm struggling to find an equivalent way to do this in C# for a .NET Core application.

I did find something that looked perfect using the CognitoAuthentication extension library https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html but upon trying the example in that the program hangs indefinitely when creating the provider:

```
public static async void GetCredsAsync()
{
    AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
        new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials()); // << hangs here
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool("poolID", "clientID", provider);
    CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("username", "clientID", userPool, provider);
    InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
    {
        Password = "userPassword"
    };

    AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
    accessToken = authResponse.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

I'm not sure if the example is relevant to .NET Core or not - the first sentence on the page says it is but there's a banner at the top saying it isn't! The banner points me to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/welcome.html but I can't seem to find what I need there.

How can I obtain AWS Cognito access tokens in .Net Core using just user pool ID, client ID and user provided username and password?

(Or why is creating the `AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient` hanging in the example?)

Any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3):

I ran into similar issue with the AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient hanging and resolved it by explicitly setting the region.

```
Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(
                new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```